# jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it, but not on perticular one div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want hide a div when user click outside of it  but not one particular div

```
  $('.todo_menu_open').click(function(){

    $('.css_content').toggle();
    $('.todo_before').toggle();
    $('.todo_after').toggle();
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = new Array();
    container.push($('.css_content'));
    container.push($('.todo_before'));
    container.push($('.todo_after'));

    $.each(container, function(key, value) {
      if (!$(value).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
          && $(value).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
      {
        $(value).hide();
      }
    });
  });
```

but not click one the container.push($('.css_content'));

Comment: Can you also post the HTML code, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope [**hasclass**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) will be useful. It return a Boolean value

```
if (!$(e.target).hasClass('css_content')){
        $(value).hide();
      }
```

You can also use `id` selector

```
    if(e.target.id !=="someIdOfContainer){
       $(value).hide();
}
```